# Having problems with .gitignore and Untracked files

Tags: git, gitignore

Greetings,

I have a weird problem with Git and using .gitignore.  I have a folder (that has contents) in my structure that is currently not getting tracked by git because it shows up under the Untracked files when I do git status.  I add it's path to .gitignore but try git status again and it is still there!  Other files/folders, I do the same thing and they disappear, but not this folder.  What am I doing wrong?

***Update***

The folder structure is:

```
folder_foo/folder_bar/folder_baz/file_foo
folder_foo/folder_bar/folder_baz/file_bar
folder_foo/folder_bar/.htaccess
```

My `.gitignore` is:

```
folder_foo/folder_bar
!folder_foo/folder_bar/.htaccess
```

When I run `git status` is says that the folder `folder_foo/folder_bar/` is untracked.
I've figured out now that if I remove the second line from the `.gitignore` then it works fine.  So I've come up with this as a fix:

```
folder_foo/folder_bar
!.htaccess
```

Why is it that I have to do it that way and not specify the exact `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Not enough information. Can you name this folder to us and show contents of your .gitignore file?

Comment: This test does not reproduce your issue: `git init; mkdir foo; touch foo/bar; echo foo > .gitignore; echo !foo/bar >> .gitignore`. Could you try that? If it produces the issue, you might want to just upgrade git. If it doesn't, could you revise the test to produce the issue?

Comment: I tried as well, cannot reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Could you just post up the `git status` output?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for me to reproduce this on git 1.7.0.4 (on Mac 10.6).

The only explanation I can think of that you are looking at a bug in an other (older) version.