# Windows global gitignore not working... "Untracked files"

Tags: windows, git, gitignore

Despite having a global gitignore on Windows OS, I am still getting a bunch of "Untracked files".

Below is a truncated list of what it looks like:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        foo/bar/__pycache__/
        foo/pkg_name.egg-info/
        scripts/MainProcess.log
        scripts/__pycache__/
        test/foo/bar/__pycache__/
        test/test_pkg_name.egg-info/
        venv/
```

**What am I doing wrong?  What am I missing?**

---

**Background**

On Windows 10 Pro my `git` version is `git version 2.34.1.windows.1`, and here's my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = C:\\Users\\username\\.config\\git\\ignore
```

`git config --list --show-origin` outputs:

```
file:C:/Users/username/.gitconfig       core.excludesfile=C:\Users\username\.config\git\ignore
```

`git check-ignore **.*` outputs nothing.

Here is the PowerShell script used to generate the global gitignore:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\.config\git

'Global/JetBrains','Global/Vim','Global/VisualStudioCode','Global/macOS','Python','Terraform' `
  | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/$PSItem.gitignore"
  } > $Env:USERPROFILE\.config\git\ignore

git config --global core.excludesfile $Env:USERPROFILE\.config\git\ignore
```

The result is a `C:\Users\username\.config\git\ignore` file in UTF-16 LE encoding with `LF` endings.  You can see the full file in a Pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/a730JHtc

Lastly, the checked out repo also has a per-repo `.gitignore` (UTF-8 encoding, `CRLF` line endings) inside that looks like this:

```
# Follow README.rst instructions on global gitignore
```

The `README.rst` instructions it speaks of have been translated into this question.

---

**Research**

There are many similar questions like this, none of them solved my problem:

- [Global Git ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore)
- [My gitignore_global is not working even though gitconfig specify the absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930938/my-gitignore-global-is-not-working-even-though-gitconfig-specify-the-absolute-pa)
- [global gitignore being, um, ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324649/global-gitignore-being-um-ignored)
- https://mike.place/2020/global-gitignore/
- https://infyom.com/blog/how-to-setup-global-git-ignore-in-window

Similar unanswered questions:

- [Global .gitignore not working, DS_Store files are still showing in untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64355852/11163122)
- [Having problems with .gitignore and Untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955882/having-problems-with-gitignore-and-untracked-files)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of your `.gitignore` file as a code block.  Also, please tell us what the encoding of that file is (UTF-16 or UTF-8) and whether it has LF or CRLF endings.

Comment: Okay @bk2204 done!  Let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your ignore file is in UTF-16.  While UTF-16 is common on Windows, it is practically unused elsewhere outside of some programming languages, and UTF-8 has mostly supplanted it.  Git accepts ignore files only in UTF-8 or other ASCII-compatible encodings (in the event your patterns contain non-UTF-8 characters), so you'll need to change your file to be in the proper format for it to work.

I would also recommend using LF endings, although I don't believe those are absolutely required for it to work.

Comment: WOW after switching to UTF-8, it works!!  I did not expect the file encoding to matter, thank you @bk2204 so much, the more you know.  Looks like the `CRLF` line ending in the local `.gitignore` was not an issue.

Comment: Relevant issue in Git for Windows: [Non UTF-8 encoded .gitignore files are silently ignored.](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3329)

Comment: This isn't a bug.  UTF-16 typically contains many NUL bytes, which makes it indistinguishable from random binary data.  ASCII-compatible encodings are always going to be required,as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, taking into account [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70842178/11163122), we can update the PowerShell global gitignore creation command to:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\.config\git
'Global/JetBrains','Global/Vim','Global/VisualStudioCode','Global/macOS','Python','Terraform' `
  | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/$PSItem.gitignore"
  } `
  | Add-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\.config\git\ignore
```

It turns out the `git config --global core.excludesfile $Env:USERPROFILE\.config\git\ignore` last line from above is not necessary.